# canvas / Создание движения элементов от центра

Tags: javascript, canvas

Помогите разобраться, почему не запускается анимация движение кругов с центра экрана в радиальном направлении ?

```js
  window.onload = function () {

    var canvas, n;
    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

    var currentHeight = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.height = currentHeight;
    canvas.width = currentHeight;
    n = 20;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function createCircle() {

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        var radius, x, y, color;
        var step = 1;
        radius = 4;
        color = "#00e676";
        x = (canvas.width) / 2;
        y = (canvas.height) / 2;

        for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            var R = step * radius;
            var f = Math.PI / 2;

            ctx.beginPath();
            var X = x + R * Math.cos(f + ((Math.PI * 2 * i) / n));
            var Y = y + R * Math.sin(f + ((Math.PI * 2 * i) / n));

            ctx.shadowColor ="#03561B";
            ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
            ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
            ctx.shadowBlur = 30;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;

            ctx.arc(X, Y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.fill();

                if ((i === n) && ((radius * step)) < x * 1.9) {
                    step += step * 1.2;
                    radius += radius *.1;
                    i = 0;
                }

             // ctx.clearRect(0,0,currentHeight,currentHeight); // clear canvas
        }
    }

    createCircle();

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Вроде, пытаюсь запустить через setInterval(draw, 1000); но не выходит, а если подключаю чистящий блок, то всё стирается

Comment: У вас условие не выполняется: в функции draw() n !== i, т.к. на входе i = 11, а n - 10

Comment: функция draw не рисует, она должна формировать новый кадр, сначала чистить канву, потом рисовать новую картинку, и она же в цикле объявляется, это зачем

Comment: Поправил, но цикл всё равно не стартует. (Через секунду холст просто очищается  )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не понял Ваш алгоритм, но вот, наверное как-то так

UPD: подобрал предел анимации для гладкости зацикливания и добавил вращение

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'), n = 20, s = 1;
  var currentHeight = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.height = currentHeight;
  canvas.width = currentHeight;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)

  function draw() {
  
    // немного увеличиваем коэффициент от которго зависит радиус
    s += 0.0001; 
    
    // зацикливаем чтобы этот коэффициент гулял в диапазоне (1-2.4)
    if (s > 2.4) s = 1;
    
    // сдвигаем канву в центр
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
    
    // поворачиваем на угол, зависящий от того же коэффициента что и радиус
    // этот поворот накапливается между отрисовками
    ctx.rotate(s/500.)
    
    // чистим канву
    ctx.clearRect(-canvas.width, -canvas.height, 2*canvas.width, 2*canvas.height);
    
    // сдвигаем канву обратно
    ctx.translate(-canvas.width/2, -canvas.height/2);

    // отрисовка кадра
    drawSingleFrame();
    
    // анимация появляется вот тут, эта функция говорит браузеру какую функцию нужно 
    // вызвать, когда он в следующий раз будет готов рисовать кадр (это событие происходит 
    // реже или не происходит вообще для скрытых вкладок)
    requestAnimationFrame(draw); 
  }
  
  function drawSingleFrame(){
    var radius, x, y, color;
    var step = s*=1.005;
    radius = 4;
    color = "#00e676";
    x = (canvas.width) / 2;
    y = (canvas.height) / 2;

    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
      var R = step * radius;
      var f = Math.PI / 2;

      ctx.beginPath();
      var X = x + R * Math.cos(f + ((Math.PI * 2 * i) / n));
      var Y = y + R * Math.sin(f + ((Math.PI * 2 * i) / n));

      ctx.shadowColor = "#03561B";
      ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
      ctx.shadowBlur = 30;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;

      ctx.arc(X, Y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      ctx.fill();

      if ((i === n) && ((radius * step)) < x * 1.9) {
        step += step * 1.2;
        radius += radius * .1;
        i = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 window.onload = function () {
  var currentHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvas.height = currentHeight;
  canvas.width = currentHeight;
  var n = 20,
    i = 0,
    radius, x, y, color,
    step = 1,
    X,
    Y,
    R,
    f;

  setInterval(() => {
    radius = 4;
    color = "#00e676";
    x = (canvas.width) / 2;
    y = (canvas.height) / 2;

    if (i <= n) {
      R = step * radius;
      f = Math.PI / 2;

      ctx.beginPath();
      X = x + R * Math.cos(f + ((Math.PI * 2 * i) / n));
      Y = y + R * Math.sin(f + ((Math.PI * 2 * i) / n));

      ctx.shadowColor = "#03561B";
      ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
      ctx.shadowBlur = 30;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;

      ctx.arc(X, Y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      ctx.fill();
      i++;

      if ((i === n) && ((radius * step)) < x * 1.9) {
        step += step * 1.2;
        radius += radius * .1;
        i = 0;
        setTimeout(() => {
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }, 10)
      }

      // ctx.clearRect(0,0,currentHeight,currentHeight); // clear canvas
    }


  }, 40)

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, за попытку, но это явно не то что мне необходимо. Я ещё раз переписал свой код. По задумке необходимо что круги радиальна расходились из центра

Comment: У вас получилось?

Comment: Пока что нет. Анимация не удалось добиться эффекта движения кругов

Comment: @BlackStar1991, кажется, я нашёл решение)))